# POI HSSF XLS Download issue in Servlet - New XLS file is downloading with previous sheets

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I have created Servlet, which downloading POI XLS file, on the first get/post request new file is downloading with sheet0. When i am doing second request new file is downloading with two sheets sheet0 is previous request sheet1 is new request. Like wise if I did 4 request 4 sheet is available.

I want only one sheet for new request.

Servlet Code :

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

getGet(){
    String reportname = request.getParameter("repname");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportname + ".xls");
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    int i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        sheet.createRow(i);
        HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(i).createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Test"+i);
        i++;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wb.write(outByteStream);
    byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(outArray);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
}
```

Web code :

```
<body>
    <a href="../../DownloadXLS?repname=Myreport1">One</a>
    <a href="../../DownloadXLS?repname=Myreport2">two</a>
    <a href="../../DownloadXLS?repname=Myreport3">three</a>
</body>
```

I want only one sheet at the time of n'th request also.

- Where I am wrong?
- Any logical mistake?

Comment: Did my response solve your problem? If so please accept the answer, or elaborate what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your servlet gets instantiated once when you start your program. Meaning that the line

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
```

only gets called once. So every time you call getGet() it will reuse the *wb* variable and create another sheet.

If you move the HSSFWorkbook constructor inside your getGet() it will create a new one to work with for each get request.